# IF Exists .... Drop Table is running for ever in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a script which begins with the following:

```sql
IF EXISTS (
        SELECT NAME
        FROM [dbname]
        WHERE NAME = N'tblname'
            AND xtype = 'U'
        )
    Drop table [tblname]
```

This part is taking ages. The other part of the script like `SELECT....INTO` take about 5 second when run independently. But when run with the `IF Exists` it was running for more than 1 hour and I stopped it.

The full script is as follows:

```
IF EXISTS (
    SELECT NAME
    FROM [dbname]
    WHERE NAME = N'[tblname]'
        AND xtype = 'U'
    )
Drop table [tblname]

 --84783

    select 
    dw.*
    ,[AttendanceType]
    ,isnull(apt.Location_Name,'London') as 
    LocationName
    ,GETDATE() TableLastRefreshed
    into [tblname]
    from [ref].[DW100] dw
```

this is taking for ever please can you help

Comment: Show us your whole script, not just a snippet of it.

Comment: from `[db name]`?

Comment: BTW, 2016 version and higher supports `drop table if exists tableName`...

Comment: The lightly cause of  these symptoms is blocking. This may be due to another session using the table to be dropped and/or an uncommitted schema modification. Run `EXEC sp_who2;` and examine the BlkBy column for a blocking session_id.

Comment: The problem is on dropping the table. I tried with right hand click on the table and delete it, but it is not deleting it. Using EXEC sp_who2 I found out SPID 54 is blocking it. But I have already killed this SPID, it is showing that it is blocked.

Comment: After killing SPID for blocking a query, how long does it take to release the blocking. I killed the blocking SPID two hours ago and it is still showing as blocking when I run EXEC sp_who2

Comment: The killed session will go terminate after it rolls back the current transaction. You can run `KILL <spid> WITH STATUSONLY` to get the status.

Answer (score 1):

I usually do:

```sql
IF OBJECT_ID('MY_TABLE') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE MY_TABLE
```

The reason why You have to wait so long is probably because Your `SELECT FROM [db name]` creates a lock and `DROP TABLE` is waiting until this lock is released... and it can't because it's waiting until Your whole query finish.

More about locks https://codingsight.com/main-concept-of-sql-server-locking/

Comment: The problem is on dropping the table. I tried with right hand click on the table and delete it, but it is not deleting it. Using EXEC sp_who2 I found out SPID 54 is blocking it. But I have already killed this SPID, it is still showing that SPID 54 is still blocking it.

Answer (score 0):

When I re-started the SQL server this was resolved.As Dan Guzman rightly said the cause of the problem was blocking. This may be due to another session using the table to be dropped and/or an uncommitted schema modification.